# sql server assign declared variable to a column name

Tags: sql-server-2008, variables, declare

Is there a way to do the following?

```
declare @start_date int
declare @end_date int

set @start_date = 202003
set @end_date = 202004

select
    'Total_Units' as Metric_Description
    ,cast(count(*) as varchar(max)) as @end_date
from table
```

I am trying to use the @end_date as the name of a column in a query result, in other words, I am trying to do this without having the change the 202004 in all the multiple queries each month

```
select
    'Total_Units' as Metric_Description
    ,cast(count(*) as varchar(max)) as '202004'
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
declare @start_date int
declare @end_date varchar(20)

set @start_date = 202003
set @end_date = '202004'

declare @query varchar(max)

set @query = 'select
    ''Total_Units'' as Metric_Description
    ,cast(count(*) as varchar(max)) as [' + @end_date + ']
from table'


exec sp_sqlexec @query
```